# Understanding Chrome performance counters

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome

So, um, I was reading [**this post**](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/) about js performance and whatnot, and I figured I'd try out the timeline profiler on my site. and I'm seeing some rather alarming results, with upwards of 7k DOM nodes and 1k event listeners being in memory, while the page only has ~300 DOM elements when doing `$('*').length`, so where are the other 7k elements? and what about the event listeners? I `.empty` the containers where I place my new HTML before doing so, so I'm not sure where this is coming from.

[image]
[enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAbwW.png)

Is my site an impending disaster? Is this normal behavior?

I should mention the timeline describes the page after a few views have been rendered, and that the site is a single page with ajax calls. views basically clear a container and place their html there, which comes from template functions compiled with mustache.

PD: In case anyone cares, [this is the site](http://www.ponyfoo.com)

Comment: I'd guess "DOM nodes count" includes text nodes and other non-element-nodes, while `$('*')` only selects elements. Sure, the ratio still is too high.

Comment: I get 3184 Dom nodes, 25 event nodes. `$("*").length` is 1764 for me, add in the text nodes that won't be counting and that's about right. Try using an incog window, I suspect all those event listeners are coming from one of your extensions. Don't forget those code samples will be littered with spans. NBrut looks good.